# How do I implement error checking

Tags: c#

Hi guys I have this app that does printing based on items on a listbox.
by commatching those items with that in a directory :\slim\slimyyyy
I want to put an "ERROR CHECKING" that would give me a message that in item
on the listbox is not present in the directory .
For instance if there are 8 items or more is not in the said directory give message with the item thats not in the directory.
Find below is my code ,but my try catch does nothing.Any help is very welcome
Thanks in advance.

```
{
        //var printList = new List();
        try
        {
            var printList = new List();
            string dir = @"C:\slim\slimyyyy";
            if (Directory.Exists(dir))
            {
                string[] pdf_specFiles = Directory.GetFiles(dir);
                if (pdf_specFiles.Length > 0)
                {
                    foreach (object item in listBox1.Items)
                    {
                        foreach (string file in pdf_specFiles)
                        {
                            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
                            if (fileName == item.ToString())
                            {
                                printList.Add(Path.GetFullPath(file));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    foreach (string file in printList)
                    {
                        PrintDocument(file);
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000); // wait 10 second say
                        Application.DoEvents(); // keep UI responsive if Windows Forms app
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You are missing Item(s).", "ERROR");
        }
    }>
```

Comment: Are any of your error conditions supposed to throw an exception? If not, try/catch won't do anything.

Comment: If you put a break point into your catch, will you go there?

Comment: What can I do Bradley? if I try to dump in an item on the listbox that I know is not in C:\slim\slimyyyy  'NO errors"

Comment: Add a throw(new exception()) inside your try block it will generate an exception.

Comment: Hi Fjodr, am newbie with  c# ,so just adding throw(new Exception()){"what ever would do the trick?"}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's the new solution:
 - Please put `using System.Linq` on top of form

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    const string directoryPath = @"C:\slim\slimyyyy";
    var printList = new List<string>();
    foreach (string item in listBox1.Items)
    {
        var currentFilePath = Path.Combine(directoryPath, item);
        if (File.Exists(currentFilePath))
        {
            printList.Add(item);
        }
    }
    if (!printList.Any())
    {
        MessageBox.Show("File doesn't exist");
        return;
    }
    foreach (string file in printList)
    {
        PrintDocument(file);
        // Why you want to wait?? Let it print.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, I am getting this error "A local variable named 'file' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'file', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else"

Comment: Its File In Linq Query. Try this  var fileName = pdf_specFiles.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Equals(item.ToString()));

Comment: Hi Gaurav ,Program does nothing now just kind stood frozen

Comment: I think the try catch is screwed up ,I just want to detects units that are not in @"c:slim\slimyyyy" and ur methdd looks right to me.

Comment: seriously I did not do that Gaurav

Comment: Works great Gaurav, I just gotta tweek it lil bit, but thanks man I really appreciate your help :) +2